# how to resize yiiwheels.widgets.highcharts.WhHighCharts

Tags: php, yii, charts, size

I use yii and this widget for making a chart:

**yiiwheels.widgets.highcharts.WhHighCharts**

but it turns out that it couldn't be sized as I want. It just fit as wide as my screen. 
I want to make it a bit smaller. But how? I've tried adding `'htmlOption'=>array('height'=>..., 'width'=>...)`
but it makes no change.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$label=array();
$nilai=array();

foreach($grafikskor->getData() as $i=>$ii)
{
    $label[$i]=$ii['idsimulasi'];
    $nilai[$i]=(int)$ii['nilai'];
}

$this->widget(
    'yiiwheels.widgets.highcharts.WhHighCharts',
    array(
        'pluginOptions' => array(
            'title'  => array('text' => 'Grafik Simulasi Siswa'),
            'xAxis'  => array(
                'categories' => $label
            ),
            'yAxis'  => array(
                'title' => array('text' => 'Skor Simulasi')
            ),
            'series' => array(
                array('data'=>$nilai)
            )
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'width'=> '250',
            'heght' => '100'
        )
    )
);;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:250px; height:100px;')
```